# Identifying origin of strange queries in Google BigQuery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

Im using Google BigQuery from distinct sources (personal computer, work computer, etc.) from both python's API and BQ UI, all of them using the same account. Recently I was looking for an old query I made on the UI and found some really strange queries that were in the history. They were all made using my account but I have no idea where they came from. It is my understanding that the only queries saved in the UI history are the ones that are being made from the UI, but I'm sure I didn't made them.

They all resemble queries I actually did run, but were made at unusual times and look like something a human won't write.

I'm seeing things like this:

`` SELECT SUM(t0c0d1.f0_) AS t0c0d1_qt_hr6xtcdtxb, t0c0d1.yearmonth FROM `table` AS t0c0d1 GROUP BY t0c0d1.yearmonth ``

`SELECT t0.dia, t0.hour, COUNT(1.000000000000000) AS t0_qt_9bitlns7xb FROM table AS t0 GROUP BY t0.day, t0.hour`

I have no programmed queries so it's not that.

Any idea of what is going on or what can I do to find the source of this queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are from Data Studio. If you check Data Studio, I'm guessing you'll find the reports you have that are generating them.